# Access to a project subfolder

Tags: m2doc

I would like to insert images in my m2doc template from an image folder in a library.

I access the library with the following query :
`self.siblings().eContents(libraries::LibraryReference).library.eInverse(capellamodeller::Library)`

But I can't find any folder with `myLibrary.eContents()` and `myLibrary.ownedFolders` returns null.

I also tried with `myLibrary.getProject()` and `myLibrary.getRootContainer()` but the result is the same.

Is it possible to access a subfolder in a project?

Thank you for your help,

Eva

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how images are stored, but if the file is on the file system you can access it via its path either relative to your .genconf file or absolute.

Maybe someone on the [Capella forum](https://forum.mbse-capella.org) could give you more details about image storage in Capella libraries.